# Story whose main character is an anti entropy focus

Tags: story-identification

I read half of a novel once whose main character was a sort of anti entropy focus.  He was immortal and remembered being a roman soldier. He didn't seem to have any direct control over the power. Things around him began to have less entropy. There was one scene where he sat in a junk car long enough and it became like new and full of fuel.

The plot was starting to hint that he was the tool of some higher more powerful being in it's conflict with the forces of entropy.

Comment: The anti-entropy part sounds familiar, but the Roman soldier part markedly does not ring a bell for me.  Do you possibly remember a section where the Mississippi river valley, at this future point in time totally concrete, begins to revert to its arboreal state?

Comment: I don't remember that part but it may be in the part I didn't read

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial match to your description, but in Daniel Keys Moran's book [The Armageddon Blues](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1616) the character of Georges Mordreaux is just as you describe but he was born in 1712 so he couldn't have been a Roman soldier.

> He was born in 1712, with a talent. Entropy tended to decrease in his vicinity; objects became more orderly, more energetic. He survived two and a half centuries and then some, despite three incidents that should have killed him, and then he battled a device from seven and a half centuries in his future.

He does buy an old car, a 1966 Camaro, from a second hand car dealer that becomes like new just by him sitting in it.

The story is about a woman from the future who goes back in time to try and avert a nuclear war that happened in 2007 and almost destroyed the world. I confess I forget what role Georges played in the story since it's ages since I last read the book.